# Should I use Rust 1.0-alpha or the nightly version?

Tags: rust

Just started learning Rust. On Wikipedia it says pre-alpha stable version is not recommended because the language moves fast. But is 1.0-alpha stable now to use for learning?

I wanted to install Rust using homebrew on mac, but it only has the 1.0-alpha version.

Comment: A really cool project is [multirust](https://github.com/brson/multirust) - it allows you to have multiple versions of rust installed (nightly, alpha, (the future) beta, custom-built), pings you when new versions of the nightlies are out, and automates the update process (`multirust update nightly`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start now, and use the nightlies as suggested by Dietrich. The biggest conceptual chunks of the language (such as lifetimes and ownership) are extremely unlikely to change between now and 1.0-beta or 1.0. The biggest "issues" you will experience will be with the standard library - what features it exposes and how. At worst, that means you have to change some code and read a changelog each time you update the compiler.

As for how to install it, homebrew has a `--head` option you can use to install the newest code. You may just want to download the version from the website though or use rustup.sh.

Comment: thanks, installed nightly from the site, having fun right now.